# Asynchronous loaded Image is not reusable inside the same view

Tags: image, asynchronous, swiftui, xml-parsing

I have a problem with the asyncimage.

Here is the link to the files
https://www.vadimbulavin.com/asynchronous-swiftui-image-loading-from-url-with-combine-and-swift/

The image of the bottom bar does not change on button action. How could I fix it and could you explain it?

podcastIndex is @Publisched inside the PodcastParser Class

The text changes and it's no problem, but the image is alway the same.

Here is my ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var podcastParser = PodcastParser()

init() {
    podcastParser.loadData()
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(podcastParser.podcasts.indices) { index in
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    podcastParser.podcastIndex = index
                    print(podcastParser.podcasts[podcastParser.podcastIndex].imageUrl)
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        AsyncImage(
                            url: podcastParser.podcasts[index].imageUrl,
                            placeholder: {
                                Text("Loading...")
                            },
                            image: { Image(uiImage: $0).resizable() }
                        )
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        Text(podcastParser.podcasts[index].name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    VStack {
        HStack {
            AsyncImage(
                url: podcastParser.podcasts[podcastParser.podcastIndex].imageUrl,
                placeholder: {
                    Text("Loading...")
                },
                image: { Image(uiImage: $0).resizable() }
            )
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            Text(podcastParser.podcasts[podcastParser.podcastIndex].name)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally when you have such problems, there's always a brute force solution to force view update using `id` modifier.

```
AsyncImage(
    url: podcastParser.podcasts[podcastParser.podcastIndex].imageUrl,
    placeholder: {
        Text("Loading...")
    },
    image: { Image(uiImage: $0).resizable() }
).id(podcastParser.podcasts[podcastParser.podcastIndex].imageUrl)
```

With system `AsyncImage` this would be the only solution, but in your case you're using open source solition, so can modify it to fix the problem.

Replacing `StateObject` with `ObservedObject` in `AsyncImage.swift` solves the problem in this case. I'm using same approach with this library and haven't faced any issues so far.

Comment: now I have another problem! After Tap to the List-Button Element all my images inside of List-Element will be reset to the placeholder image. (view will be rebuild, I think). If I change back to `StateObject` is everything fine. Any idea?

Comment: @Leff you mean when you tap on the cell to select bottom image? It doesn't happen to me.. Have you took `AsyncImage` source code from from [this repository](https://github.com/V8tr/AsyncImage)?

Comment: yes, I used the same repository. I use this case inside other project and the view get all data over `@EnvironmentObject var radioPlayer: RadioPlayer`

Maybe it makes problems inside of the parent object?

Comment: @Leff  When you updated your list in your model and using `podcastParser.podcasts.indices` in your `List` or `ForEach` this would rebuild all the cells. In case with `@StateObject` it not updating same as it doesn't update at the bottom, so it's a bug, not a feature =) Create a new question, because the answer is too big for a comment.

Comment: okay, I will do it tomorrow! I've just rebuild the structure of the main project to the playground and it works without problems. Strange, that the same structure doesn't work inside the main project. I have to find a bug somewhere... ;)